Why does an empty space get displayed instead of the bitmap?
i am currently working on a c#/xaml project, where i try to create a video database. I want to display bitmap images alongside different buttons, to act as preview pictures. When i run my code the buttons get displayed correctly, but where the images should go i only get a blank space. I dont get any error messages.
Here is my Code:
I first create a grid, consisting of the buttons and an bitmap image.
public Grid SearchResult(string name, string mode)
{
    // create grid
    Grid grid = new Grid();
    grid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
    grid.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
    grid.RowDefinitions.Add(MakeRowDefinition(90));
    grid.RowDefinitions.Add(MakeRowDefinition(40));

    WrapPanel panel = new WrapPanel();
    panel.Height = 40;

    Grid.SetRow(panel, 1);
    grid.Children.Add(panel);

    // add preview image
    Image image = new Image();
    image.BeginInit();
    Uri path = new Uri(@"data/" + mode.ToLower() + "/individual/" + Path.GetFileName(name) + ".png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    image.Source = new BitmapImage(path);
    image.Height = 90;
    image.Width = 160;
    image.EndInit();
    Grid.SetRow(image, 0);
    grid.Children.Add(image);

    // add buttons to panel (play, add to playlist, edit)
    Button playButton = MakeButton("play");
    playButton.Click += PlayButton_Click;

    Button addToPlaylistButton = MakeButton("+ playlist");
    addToPlaylistButton.Click += AddToPlaylistButton_Click;

    Button editButton = MakeButton("edit");
    editButton.Click += EditButton_Click;

    panel.Children.Add(playButton);
    panel.Children.Add(addToPlaylistButton);
    panel.Children.Add(editButton);

    return grid;
}

I then add the grid to a WrapPanel inside another grid.
public Grid MakeResultLayout(ref List<string> searchParameters) // will create initial layout for search results
{

    // clear Results Panel and add panels for search parameters and searchresults
    resultLayout.Children.Clear();

    resultLayout.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition()); // search parameters
    resultLayout.RowDefinitions.Add(databaseUI.MakeRowDefinition(10)); // spacer
    resultLayout.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition()); // search results

    WrapPanel searchParameterPanel = new WrapPanel();
    Grid.SetRow(searchParameterPanel, 0);
    resultLayout.Children.Add(searchParameterPanel);

    WrapPanel searchResultPanel = new WrapPanel();
    Grid.SetRow(searchResultPanel, 2);
    resultLayout.Children.Add(searchResultPanel);

    // add Buttons for each searchparameter
    foreach (string parameter in searchParameters)
    {
        Button button = databaseUI.MakeButton(parameter);
        button.Click += SearchParameterButton_Click;
        searchParameterPanel.Children.Add(button);
    }

    searchResultPanel.Children.Clear();
    foreach (string result in foundResults)
    {
        Grid grid = databaseUI.SearchResult(result, mode);
        searchResultPanel.Children.Add(grid);
    }

    return resultLayout;
}

I then add this grid to yet another WrapPanel.
Grid grid = MakeResultLayout(ref searchParameters);
DatabasePanel.Children.Clear();
DatabasePanel.Children.Add(grid);

This WrapPanel, called DatabasePanel, i created using xaml, as part of a Window.
<WrapPanel x:Name="DatabasePanel" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1"/>

I know it is a lot of WrapPanels and Grids inside each other. I use these to create the layout for my application. I unfortunately cant add my whole code to this post, since it consist of multiple scripts adding up to more than 1000 lines of code in total. But these should be the important parts.
This is how the resulting layout looks (only the searchResult WrapPanel shown in the image). The images should be displayed above the Buttons.
Resulting Layout
Any ideas on why i get a blank space, instead of an image?
I already checked the paths for the images. They apperat to be correct. Also there are no error messages for any parts of the program.
I also took a look at multiple forum post and tutorials, but could not figure out, why the images dont get displayed correctely. I do have to admit tho, that the WrapPanels and Grids do make it harder to figure out what is going wrong.

Uri path is apparenty a relative path. Make sure it is valid against the current working directory of your application. Try loading images from absolute paths.

I tried swapping out the relative path for the corresponding absolute path. This seemed to do the trick. Thank you for your help @Clemens. (Out of curiosity i tried writing both the relative and the absolute path to the console. I could tell no difference between the two, so i am not sure, why the relative path does not work in this instance.)

First of all you should use Path.Combine instead of manually concatenating path elements with separators. Then try with UriKind.Relative to see what happens.

Add Image control "event handlers": Image.ImageFailed Event. "If the Source is a BitmapImage and it fails to load, due to a corrupt header, both the DecodeFailed and ImageFailed events occur."
